# How to scale elastic search with one shared NAS area

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift

I have installed one elastic search node on openshift architecture and is running as a container inside a pod. the data is mounted on a NAS area (500 GB).

Hardware configuration :
16GB ram with 8GB heap allocated to elastic search and remaining to lucene.

The issue i am facing is my kibana queries are timing out or very slow. I have 5 shards with daily index of around 20gb. Retention period is 5 days.

2 users are using it currently and goal is for 50 or more people to use it.

I would like to host multiple instances of my elastic search  against this one NAS.

I read few articles where it states that one instance should map to one shared area to avoid concurrency issues.

Can someone please suggest how do i go about achieving this?  as i think the problem lies with one instance and i need to scale it.

Thanks for the help.

Please note I don't have dynamic provisioning of storage. NAS is the only thing i have. also if i try to start more than one pod, it fails as you cannot mount the same area.
Statefulset needs dynamic provisioning which i don't have.

Comment: FYI, Lucene relies on file system behavior that NFS does not supply. Data corruption and other problems can occur at Elasticsearch, refer here: [PERSISTENT ELASTICSEARCH STORAGE](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html#aggregated-logging-persistent-storage) for more details. You had better to use block storage for your ES.